# How to do this list with the conditions stated in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

it must be a list of 4 item whereby they should look like this:

- 1) Human:(checkbox)tick
- 2) Gender:(dropdown)Female,Male,Unknown
- 3) Name:(text box)Early Grey Tea
- 4) Summary:(Human:yes, Gender:Female, Name:Early Grey Tea)

the 4th section is a read only section which will auto update as the other 3 sections are filled in

Comment: what you mean?????????????????????????

Comment: its a ordered list where 
first option: tick/no tick...
second option: Select an option from dropdown... 
third : Fill in text box...
fourth:(Autofill and read only) Should show all the choices made in the previous 3, example <First option: yes> <Second option: Something>...

Comment: Please make your question statement clear to help you with suggestions.

Comment: You need to learn jQuery functions and html struct. You should not ask a question like that. You have to post some codes.

Comment: how much are you willing to pay me? :P :P

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script>function generateSummary(){
  console.log("inside summary");
   var human='';
  if(document.getElementById("isHuman").checked)  {
    human="yes";
  }else{
    human="no"
  }
 var gender=document.getElementById("chkGender").value;
 var  name=document.getElementById("name").value;
  console.log("summary="+human+""+gender+""+name);
  document.getElementById("summaryTextBox").value="(Human:"+human+",Gender:"+gender+",Name:"+name+")";
}enter code here</script>
</head>
<body>
  <ol>
  <li><label>Human<input id="isHuman" type="checkbox"/></label></li><li>
  <label>Gender</label><select id="chkGender">

  <option>Male</option>
    <option>Female</option>
  <option>unknown</option>
  </select></li><li>
<label>Name:</label><input id="name" type="text" onblur="generateSummary()"/>
</li><li>
<label>Summary:</label><input id="summaryTextBox" type="text" disabled/>
</li></ol>
</body>
</html>
```